# RSQLite parametrised query with vectors as parameters

Tags: r, rsqlite

I am new to `SQL` and its syntax, and I cannot understand how to pass multiple values (e.g. vector or list) to a single parameter in a parametrised query in `R` using `RSQLite`.

I have a two tables database (`myTCGA`) with data coming from RNASeq data. The first (`tcga_P`) contains expression values (`FPKM`) of samples for some genes, while (`tcgaMeta`) contains the metadata information of those samples.

```
#tcga_P
      FPKM           Sample                 Tissue GeneName
5550 0.0633 TCGA-AB-2803-03A Acute_Myeloid_Leukemia  PLEKHN1
5551 0.2390 TCGA-AB-2805-03A Acute_Myeloid_Leukemia  PLEKHN1
5552 0.0253 TCGA-AB-2806-03A Acute_Myeloid_Leukemia  PLEKHN1
5553 0.0385 TCGA-AB-2807-03A Acute_Myeloid_Leukemia  PLEKHN1
5554 0.0326 TCGA-AB-2808-03A Acute_Myeloid_Leukemia  PLEKHN1
5555 0.2836 TCGA-AB-2810-03A Acute_Myeloid_Leukemia  PLEKHN1

# tcgaMeta (only few columns)
SampleIndex         SampleID        SubjectID Tumor.Type         Sample.Type
  1           0 TCGA-01-0628-11A TCGA-01-0628         OV Solid Tissue Normal
  2           1 TCGA-01-0630-11A TCGA-01-0630         OV Solid Tissue Normal
  3           2 TCGA-01-0631-11A TCGA-01-0631         OV Solid Tissue Normal
```

I want to extract the expression values from `tcga_P` of only the samples that belong to specific groups (e.g. all lung samples). To do so, I wrote a query that looks like this

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)

myGene <- "PLEKHN1"
myTissue <- "lung"
myCancer <- "Lung Adenocarcinoma"
selectedSamples <- dbGetQuery(myTCGA, 
     "SELECT A.*
     FROM tcga_P A 
     WHERE A.GeneName = $gene AND
           A.Sample in (SELECT B.SampleID FROM tcgaMeta B 
                WHERE B.Tissue = $tissue AND 
                      B.`Disease.TCGA.` = $cancer )
     ",param = list(gene=myGene,tissue=myTissue,cancer=myCancer))
 # from long to wide
 selectedSamplesWide <- dcast(selectedSamples,GeneName~Sample, value.var = "FPKM",fun.aggregate = sum)
```

This query correctly returns the values only if I supply one gene at the time, but it fails if I try to extract the values from multiple genes (`myGene <- c("PLEKHN1","PSMD12"))`

```
Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params) : 
Parameter 2 does not have length 2.
```

I could loop (`sapply`) through the genes in the vector, make the sql call one gene at the time and bind the results together, but I would like to do everything inside the sql call.

So far I tried with

```
WHERE A.GeneName IN ($gene)
WHERE A.GeneName IN (SELECT C.GeneName FROM $gene C)
```

I also tried to convert `myGene` to a `data.frame` and treat the genes as a column. It is superfluous to say that nothing worked.

What am I missing? how are the parameters passed to `param = list()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, the `WHERE` clause with equality, `=`, expects one value where you are attempting to evaluate expression to two values. However, the `WHERE` with `IN` allows for multiple values:

```sql
WHERE A.GeneName IN ('PLEKHN1', 'PSMD12', ...)
```

For an open-ended number of values, consider dynamically creating the prepared statement with `paste` + `collapse` and binding parameter values with `setNames` and `as.list`:

```
myGene <- c("PLEKHN1", "PSMD12")
myTissue <- "lung"
myCancer <- "Lung Adenocarcinoma"

myPlaceHolders <- paste0("$gene", seq_along(myGene))

sql <- paste0("SELECT A.*
               FROM tcga_P A 
               WHERE A.GeneName IN (", paste(myPlaceHolders, collapse=", "), ") 
                 AND A.Sample in (SELECT B.SampleID 
                                  FROM tcgaMeta B 
                                  WHERE B.Tissue = $tissue 
                                    AND B.`Disease.TCGA.` = $cancer)
             ")

myGeneParams <- as.list(setNames(myGene, gsub("\\$", "", myPlaceHolders)))
paramList <- c(myGeneParams, tissue=myTissue, cancer=myCancer)

selectedSamples <- dbGetQuery(myTCGA, sql, param = myParamList)
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/USGBU70863) *(for prepared statement and parameter output not query run)*

Comment: thank you for the solution and the clear explanation. I had to escape the gsub pattern `gsub("\\$", "", myPlaceHolders)`, but apart from that, it worked.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!